# What do I need to re-index after importing products

Tags: import, indexing, magmi

I'm importing a bunch or products with Magmi, after each import I need to re-index for the products to show up on the frontend.  Do I need to re-index everything?

This is what I'm re-indexing

- Product Attributes
- Product Prices
- Catalog URL Rewrites
- Product Flat Data
- Category Flat Data
- Category Products
- Catalog Search
- Stock Status
- Tag Aggregation Data

Do I need to re-index all of these or just a select few?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to reindex `Category Flat Data` and `Product Attributes` if you import only products.
Most probably you don't need to reindex `Tag Aggregation Data` either since no new tags are added.
The rest are mandatory.

Comment: for `Category Flat Data` what if I assign the products to a category?  Or is this index just for when I add or modify a category? Also I would have thought `Product Attributes` would need to be re-indexed as I added products with new attributes, I guess it is just for when you add or modify attributes

Comment: If you add new attributes you need to reindex the product attributes. And the flat category index needs rebuilding only if you modify the categories.