# Magento 1.9.2.1 Product Upload Via .csv file does not generate url rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9, import, url-rewrite, csv, product-urls

I uploaded products via .csv file but the URLs does not get created/generated. I wonder if anyone can tell whether this is the expected behavior or there is a bug?

Updated Question I have uploaded a product with "url_key" called test-url the product get uploaded without errors but url rewrite doe not get generated!

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner Do you happen to know ?

Comment: Where did you upload the csv and what does its structure look like? What do you mean exactly with URLs not getting created? Talking about `url_key`?

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner That's right "url_key" in System->Import Product and append complex data

Answer (score 1):

`url_key` is not a mandatory attribute. Magento will assume the product's name (with some preg_replace) if not specified.
This means, if your product name is for example "Test Test" your initial `url_key` will be `test-test` - even though it is not  visible in the backend at this point.
You may fill that field on your own while importing, but please make sure you use valid characters only to avoid confusions.

Comment: see updated question you answer isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you try to run the reindexer after your import?

Comment: Yes I know what i does and it does generate all the "url_key" rewrite fine but why it does not generate when the product is inserted with .cvs file? and again is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: In general (depended on your configuration, but by default it would be set so) Magento will perform required re-indexing "on save". This means, when you create a new product manually from backend, Magento would perform these tasks in the background by the time you save the product. This however is not the case when you import products. An import basically always requires you to re-index your catalog manually. Mandatory re-indexing processes got mentioned by @Marius in this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79383/what-do-i-need-to-re-index-after-importing-products).

Comment: That looks like to me then the expected behaviour  when importing products with .csv files  so I will always have to perform "Catalog URL Rewrites" Reindex Data Action.